# Move a JDialog from outside the screen to a position in screen

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm trying to create a notifications system.
I'm trying to make a JDialog thats moves from outside the screen to a specific position. I'm using [timing framework](https://java.net/projects/timingframework) and I can move the dialog from a position to another, but when I try to specify a position outside the screen the dialog does not do that.

This code:

```
dialog.setLocation(new Point(-dialog.getWidth(), 10));
```

Should put the dialog on the right side outside the screen but it does not.

I did try to use some notifications libraries as:

- JCommunique
- jtelegraph
- twinkle
- jcarrierpigeon

But any of those libraries work properly for my needs.

Comment: Who do you want to position the `JDialog` offscreen? Would just hiding the dialog (`setVisible(false)`) accomplish the same?

Comment: "but it does not." - describe what happens / what's the problem. You don't give enough information about the problem you have.

Comment: No, I want to slide the dialog from outside the screen.

Comment: Leet me explain more. The dialog should start in a position off the screen, and when the timing starts, it should getting into the screen.
What happens is that the dialog start in the edge of the screen completely visible.

Comment: 1) Create a BufferedImage from the JDialog.  2) Calculate the position of the BufferedImage, from off the screen to the desired position in small increments.  3) Draw the BufferedImage for each increment.  4) Make the JDialog visible after the BufferedImage is in the correct position.  5) Profit!!

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem